# How to create an array of values that exist in another array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I cannot find a method that could help me.
I have a list of expenses that contain the name of a specific category and a list of categories that contain a color. 
I use react-chartjs-2 and chartjs in a react application.
My problem is that, the array I create from verifying the match between expense.category and category.name returns the same order of the values despite the order of expenses.
For example if the function returns 2 expenses, the first ordering will be:

expense 1, expense 2,
value of expense 1, value of expense 2,
color of expense 1, color of expense 2,

but when I apply a filter (by amount for example) and the order changes, for example:

expense 2, expense 1,
value of expense 2, value of expense 1,
color of expense 1, color of expense 2 ... the colors won't change the order.

```
  const labels = props.expenses.map((expense) => capitalize(expense.category));

  const amounts = props.expenses.map((expense) => expense.amount/100 );

  let colors = [];
  props.expensesCategories.filter((category) => {
    labels.filter((label) => {
      label.toLowerCase() === category.name.toLowerCase() ? colors.unshift(category.color) : '#000'
    })
  });
```

This data is used in the data object of chart js:

```
const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      data: amounts,
      backgroundColor: colors
    }]
  };
```

I tried map, filter, forEach and for the colors array I tried push, unshift.

Please let me know if you guys know how to fix this. Thank you very much

Comment: Can you share the expenses and expensesCategories array (a sample) ?

Comment: @Theo problem not clear enough can you throw more light on the final data you wish to receive.

Comment: @TarekEssam. So the expenses array would look like:   
[{description: 'Rent', category: 'house', amount: 123000, createdAt: 10/19/2018}, {description: 'Apples', category: 'food', amount: 240000, createdAt: 10/18/2018}]  

And the expensesCategories would look like:  
[{name: 'house', color: '#ddd'}, {name: 'food', color: '#333'}]  

Basically this data comes ordered by date as default. So 'Rent' will come first, but I made 'Apples' cost more so when I order by amount, they would come first...the problem is that when I create the colors array, the colors don't change order

Comment: @philip_nunoo you can find the app running at https://budget-app-money.herokuapp.com - Notice the chart colors change when filtering by amount instead of date.